# Fastest way to seek a word in very large binary files?

Tags: android, search, grep, large-files

I am writing a function in Android application which can seek a keyword in many large binary files.
Currently, I am using "grep" command to check if the keyword exists in each file?

Because, there are many LARGE binary file, so I am facing to time problem.
I wish to have your help.

My problem:

1) Seek keywords in many large binary files

2) A better solution than GREP to resolve time problem

Comment: If you just want to know if the word is there, use `grep` with option `-l` (L). This way, if a match is found it will show the file name and stop searching further matches.

Comment: @fedorqui I believe that's the default behavior for binary files. LongUni - `grep -E 'word1|word2' file1 file2` will be your fastest option but think about what a "word" means to you and consider whether or not you need some kind of word boundaries so `the` doesn't match `there` (whatever the binary file equivalent is).

Answer (score 0):

When you are searching for a byte sequence in a large file, your bottleneck will be disk bandwidth, then RAM bandwidth. Your goal is to minimize the number of data transfers, ideally to only one - disk to RAM. I would try to map the file into memory piece by piece using [FileChannel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)), then search in the backing array

Comment: Thanks msh for your comment. I must test your solution in comparison to mine. I prefer to code in c (Jni), do you have any idea for that?

Comment: same idea, mmap the file, do search (for example, use the Boyer–Moore string search algorithm)

Comment: I must try your advice.
There is --mmap option in grep command. Do you think our implementation with that option, which one is faster?